# Consumindo WEB API ASP.NET MVC 4 [ERRO]

Tags: c#, web-service, asp.net-web-api, http-status

Tenho um problema... Coloquei minha web api na locaweb... Porém se eu utilizar o link no projeto, não funciona e me retorna "StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent" . Achei que o problema era com eles e resolvi hospedar no azure, mas recebo o mesmo erro na execução da aplicação. Agora, quando eu subo minha web api no meu servidor local IIS e utilizo o link no projeto, consigo utilizar a web api na minha aplicação sem nenhum problema. Alguém saberia me ajudar?﻿

Segue meu código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o texto, não imagens do código.

Comment: Relaxa, o link que postei foi penas um teste, lógico que não vou postar o link verdadeiro que vou utilizar na aplicação

Comment: Que? Eu tô falando pra você colar o código na publicação ao invés de imagens

Comment: Entendi, é que não tinha entendido o porquê do texto e não da imagem, mas ficou claro agora.